# How do I serve multiple files without express

Tags: node.js

The tutorials I found uses express but how do I do this without it?

This is my `createServer()`.

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('./public/styles/style.css', (err, content) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/css'});
        res.end(content);
    });
    fs.readFile('./public/index.html', (err, content) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
        res.end(content);
    });
}).listen(port);
```

Sometimes this works. But, in some reloads, it either displays the stylesheet only in plain text or the stylesheet will not load.

Comment: You can use `http-server` a zero configuration command line http-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Is that a framework? Because our professor doesn't want us to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just an `if` that checks the uri of incoming request

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    if ( req.url == 'index.html' )
        ...

    if ( req.url == 'style.css' )
       ...
```

The express router is just something a little bit more clever than that - but it also has to check which route matches the incoming request.

Comment: wouldn't replace the current one or do I use `.write()`?

Comment: Never mind I got it. Thank you very much! I used the same code but inside the if's.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code delivers *both* files to any browser that accesses it. You don't have any logic to look at the request and find out which file the browser wants.

Furthermore, it's a race.  Whichever `readFile` operation finishes first gets to deliver its file first.

So, the unpredictability  of your result comes from that race.

Suggestion: use `View Source...` in your browser.